# Is there a way to track the index selections of a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegementedControl` with some numbers. When user clicks on a number, it makes that many `UITextFields` pop out.

I have this running with a switch statement and cases for each number but I wanted to clean up the code, remove the switch statement, and make a loop that checks the number chosen in the segmented control, loops through an array of text fields and makes that many text fields pop out.

It works fine when user selects a number and continues to select higher numbers.

However, if user chooses a number lower than the previous selection, it does nothing (does not hide the undesired text fields).

Is there a way to keep track of the selection made in the segmented control so that I can make some logic statements that check whether new number chosen is > or < lower than previous?

```
var chosenNumber = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
var textArray : UITextField = [item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8]

            for text in textArray[0...chosenNumber] {
            text.hidden = false
            }

          //logic here to check if newNumber is < than chosenNumber
              for text in textArray[newNumber..<8] {
                text.hidden = true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use KVO you can observe the old and new value changes...

For example:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    var kvoContextSegmentedControl: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.segmentedControl.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectedSegmentIndex", options: [.Initial, .Old, .New], context: &kvoContextSegmentedControl)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if ((keyPath == "selectedSegmentIndex") && context == &kvoContextSegmentedControl) {
            let oldValue = change![NSKeyValueChangeOldKey]
            let newValue = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]
            debugPrint("OldValue: \(oldValue)")
            debugPrint("NewValue: \(newValue)")
        }else{
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }
```

Outputs the following:

1) When the view loads (0 is the default selected segment):

```
OldValue: nil
NewValue: Optional(0)
```

2) When the different segments are clicked:

i) Clicked on 3 (when 0 was the last):

```
OldValue: Optional(0)
NewValue: Optional(3)
```

ii) Clicked on 2 (when 3 was the last):

```
OldValue: Optional(3)
NewValue: Optional(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficient approach will be to keep a variable that holds the last selected index and then check it's value when you need.

1. Just take two variable one is currentIndex and another is prevIndex.
2. In "Value Changed" method of UISegmentedControl ,  just put the value of currentIndex in prevIndex and selectedSegmentIndex in currentIndex .

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I'm running print statements when a selection is made. The first time a user makes a choice it works well, prints prevSelection = 0 and currentSelection = 2. But every time I run it after that, it updates the currentSelection but it always maintains the prevSelection as 0.

Answer (score 0):

why not a switch statement on chosenNumber?

```
switch chosenNumber {
case 0: item1.hidden = false
// etc   
default: break 
}
```

Comment: I have a switch statement now for 8 cases with a lot of text fields and labels, works great but I think it would be a lot cleaner with a loop.

Comment: you can also create another method with some parameters, like `doSomething(item1TextField, label: item1Label)` and your doSomething looks like doSomething(textField: UITextField, label: UILabel) { textField.hidden = false; label.hidden = false }